# Fluids Dynamics - Transmission Oil Dilution Problem

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have a fluids dynamics (I guess) problem with my car and I can't seem to find the answer:

I have to change my transmission oil. It has a 7 liter total capacity, but due to the torque converter, I can only drain 4 liters at a time. Thus, I have to make several **partial changes**. 
The question is: How many partial changes do I have to do in order to have a (almost) clean transmission fluid?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about physics. You could try the [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Stack Exchange](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's also much more a math problem than a physics problem. You're just looking at a discrete [mixing problem](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Modeling.aspx). This could be about a transmission, or about grain in a silo, or milk on a store shelf, etc.

Comment: @JohnRennie When do you close a question and when do you migrate it?

Comment: What do you consider to be (almost) clean? After one change you will have $4/7$ = 57% old fluid. After two changes, it will be $(4/7)^2$ = 33%. After more changes, it will be 19%, 11%, 6%, 3.5%, 2%, 1%

Comment: @mmesser314 that is the answer I was looking for. What formula is that? And if the questions stands, make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Actually, it is wrong. You drain 4 liters. I thought you left 4. Let me try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you drain 4 liters, you have 3 liters old fluid left. When you add 4 new liters to make 7, you have a mix that is 3/7 old fluid, or 43% old fluid.

If you repeat that, you wind up with a mix that is 3/7 old mix, where the old mix is 3/7 old fluid. 3/7 of 3/7 is $(3/7)^2$ = 18%.

After 3 changes, you get 3/7 or 3/7 of 3/7 old fluid, or $(3/7)^3$ = 8%.

Continuing, you get 3% and 1.5%